# Vagrant ubuntu cannot open port

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I run Ubuntu 16.04 from Vagrant (guest hostname silver). But I can't access to opened ports at guest (but vagrant forwarding works well). I start php-server for test:

> php -S 0.0.0.0:8088

```
vagrant@silver:~$ netstat -atn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:50376          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:55996          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

But can't assess to guest port 8088 from host machine.

Scan guest from host:

```
nmap -v -sT silver
Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org )
Initiating Ping Scan at 20:18
Scanning silver (192.168.33.1) [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 20:18, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Connect Scan at 20:18
Scanning silver (192.168.33.1) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 111/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 1023/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 1021/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 999/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 8000/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 2049/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Discovered open port 8001/tcp on 192.168.33.1
Completed Connect Scan at 20:18, 3.13s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for silver (192.168.33.1)
Host is up (0.0030s latency).
Not shown: 498 closed ports, 495 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
999/tcp  open  garcon
1021/tcp open  exp1
1023/tcp open  netvenuechat
2049/tcp open  nfs
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8001/tcp open  vcom-tunnel
```

Also I disable ufw:

```
vagrant@silver:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Vagrant port forwarding works well. My Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8001
config.vm.hostname = "silver"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.1"
...
```

I can't access any ports, 80, 3600, etc. But can access to 8001 - from vagrant forwarding.

Comment: weird, if you go to http://192.168.33.1:8088 you dont get anything ? when you use static IP you should not need to forward port

Comment: When I point chrome from host machine to http://192.168.33.1:8088/, I get - This site can’t be reached. I can only connect to forwarded 8001 at guest.

Comment: I test homestead box and it's worked fine for me, I can access to all ports. But when I create new box (vagrant init) based on Ubuntu or Centos, I still cannot connect to opened ports. I don't know how to troubleshoot it.